# How should three unordered categories be encoded in a bayesian network framework?

Tags: bayesian, classification, categorical-data, posterior, categorical-encoding

The [SAS FAQ](ftp://ftp.sas.com/pub/neural/FAQ2.html#A_cat) suggest that for unordered two categories I should one dummy variables, for example:

> The common practice of using target values of .1 and .9 instead of 0 and 1 prevents the outputs of the network from being directly interpretable as [posterior probabilities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Posterior_probability), although it is easy to rescale the outputs to produce probabilities (Hampshire and Pearlmutter, 1991, figure 3).

Following above logic, how do I know which target values I should use for three categories and why?